# Gradient Boosting in Matlab for classification

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

Is there any way to do gradient boosting in matlab for classification. I want to apply gradient boosting for multiclass classification, is there anyway to do it in matlab. I have read matlab's fitensemble documentation, but couldn't figure out the way to apply GB.

Comment: Did you try Google-ing _gradient boosting in matlab_?

Comment: Yes, but I could find R implementation, not Matlab. I even went went through fitensemble documentation of MATLAB, but didn't find implementation of GBM.